# Can we install multiple simulator versions at same time?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode4.5

I have currently switched to Xcode 4.5.1(iOS 6 SDK). My doubt is, whether at the same time can we install multiple simulator versions to test our app?

Answer (score 0):

Open up Xcode Preferences (Xcode->Preferences), then click on Downloads.  You should be able to download previous versions of the simulator from there.

You can then choose which one to use by using the dropdown menus near the top left next to the "Run" and "Stop" buttons.